# How to join elements of two different size arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Would I like to create a new array from the following :

```
Let array1 = [a,b,c,d]
let array2 = [x, y]
```

How to get new array like this [ay,bx,cy,dx]?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take the index with an offset and the remainder of the length of the second array.

```js
let array1 = ['a','b','c','d'],
    array2 = ['x', 'y'],
    result = array1.map((v, i) => v + array2[(i + 1) % array2.length]);
 
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great, thanks, but what if the elements are number, and I need to add array1 to array2?

Comment: it should work with numbers, too. what do you mean with *"add array1 to array2"*?

Comment: yes,`result = array1.map((v, i) => parseInt(v) * parseInt( array2[(i) % array2.length] ));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator to get the correct second array elements:

```js
let array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
let array2 = ['x', 'y'];

let result = array1.map( (item, i) => { return item + array2[(i+1) % 2] } );

console.log(result);
```